# Inner join in elastic search on one to many relationship

Tags: sql, elasticsearch

I have two documents with the following structures

```
ITEM
{
     ITEM_ID(primary Key),
     ITEM_NAME,
     ITEM_DESCRIPTION
}
ITEMREGULATION
{
     ITEMREGULATION_ID,
     ITEM_ID(Foreign Key),
     ITEMREGULATION_TYPE
}
```

These tables are in one to many relationship like  [ITEM] -----* [ITEMREGULATION].
Now I want to execute following sql query on these data -

> select * from ITEM inner join ITEMREGULATION on ITEM.ITEM_ID = ITEMREGULATION.ITEM_ID.

I have tried with Nested relationship in elastic search but ITEMREGULATION has reference of ITEM, SO it goes in infinite loop and give exception - **java.lang.StackOverflowError: null**

How can I get the above sql query in elastic search?

Comment: Can you paste your query?

Answer (score 0):

Your question has two solution.

1. `ITEM.ITEM_ID` and `ITEMREGULATION.ITEM_ID` could be of diferent type, that you compare int whit string.
2. The corect SQL-qustion is

`select * from ITEM inner join ITEMREGULATION on ITEM.ITEM_ID = ITEMREGULATION.ITEM_ID.`

Answer (score 0):

The Best Practice always is to **denormal** you'r data if it's possible.
If it's not you should define a `_parent` field for you'r **ITEMREGULATION**s. After defining parent child relationtips in elasticsearch, you can use `has_parent` `has_child` queries to simulate **joins** in **elasticsearch**.

Comment: I develop it in my java application, I use ITEM id as - @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed, store = true)
    private Long id;    and ITEMREGULATION item id as @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "item_id")
    @Field(type = FieldType.String, index = FieldIndex.analyzed, analyzer = "lowercase_keyword", store = true)
    @Parent(type = "parent")
    private Item Item;  It gives error - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parent ID property should be String

Comment: `ParentID` is a index time parameter and (probably) can't be defined in mapping annotations. set parent id when you are adding the document to elastic and it should match the `_id` field of the document in **parrent type**